# MySQL installation on Ubuntu 20.04 error when using mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install **MySQL** on **Ubuntu 20.04** and when I run the command
`sudo mysql_secure_installation`, it fails with the error below:

> ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.`

I have seen the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_set_password_auth_plugin_error) and I'm stuck on how I can solve this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099351/mysql-5-7-20-unable-to-set-root-password#answer-47099742) provide any insight? See if changing the authentication plugin helps...

Comment: [ALTER USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-user.html)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) would help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 5.7.20 unable to set root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099351/mysql-5-7-20-unable-to-set-root-password)

Comment: Sorry everyone for the late reply. The answer provided did help me resolve the issue. Once again, thanks for all your help.
@War10ck

Comment: Open the terminal application.

1. Terminate the mysql_secure_installation from another terminal using the killall command:
sudo killall -9 mysql_secure_installation
2. Start the mysql client:
sudo MySQL

3. Run the following SQL query:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'SetRootPasswordHere';
exit

4. Then run the following command to secure it:
sudo mysql_secure_installation

5. When promoted for the password enter the SetRootPasswordHere (or whatever you set when you ran the above SQL query)
That is all.

Answer (score 203):

Had the same error, solved it by running `sudo mysql` which logged me in as `root` without a password, then I ran `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'mynewpassword';`

Following this I was able to run `mysql_secure_installation` again and this time I got to choose to use existing password (the one I set with above SQL command).

However now I can no longer login without a password, running `sudo mysql` now denies `root` user access.

Comment: Yes, because the login password is `mynewpassword` (and the authentication system is changed to `mysql_native_password`)

Comment: So basically I'm in the same situation as @Tigz and I tried
`mysql -U root -p`
Then I gave the root password that I previously set but it did not log me in as root bu a local user and denied my access due to wrong password

Comment: On this issue I found this tutorial helpful https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: ^ I did as well, but had to restart mysql before it worked for me.

Comment: recommended to change back to auth_socket once installation is finish `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;`